# How to find all addresses in memory, who use a asm-variable?

Tags: disassembly

I have an address of variable, like `unk_7FF67EEFE300`. I need to find all addresses, which use asm-command, like this 
    `lea rcx, unk_7FF67EEFE300`

Answer (score 0):

That will be challenging, even with a recursive descent disassembler.  The trouble is that what you are asking can be tricky if there are anti-disassembly shenanigans going on.  That seems possible given your question.

You are likely better off using a debugger and creating a breakpoint that triggers on access to that memory location.  Under GDB, you might try:

```
 watch *0x7ff67eefe300
```

which will watch for writes and:

```
 rwatch *0x7ff67eefe300
```

which will watch for reads.

Obviously, this will require that you exercise the code to try to be sure that all of the code branches are followed, revealing which pieces of code access that location.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer! But can i look for opcode of ```lea rcx, unk_7FF67EEFE300```? I can't get how this opcode is being created...

Comment: If you are looking for only that opcode, and you know for sure that the address will always be explicit rather than a relative addressing of some kind, sure you can... but as soon as it becomes a relative address or anything other than LEA into RCX, no, you can't.

Comment: yes, i can find an address. Can you help me with opcode for searching a signature?